# HTML5 - Page turn effect

Tags: jquery, html, page-flipping

I'm trying to load external html pages in a div.  How can I have a page turn effect while loading external pages (using CSS3, HTML5 or jQuery)?

Comment: +1, I see no reason why it should be downvoted.

Answer (score 2):

Check out http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/pages/page-transitions.html as an example.  jQuery Mobile does this out of the box.

Comment: Thanks for your replay, I'll try and let you know. Thanks again.

Comment: I need a flip book effect while loading external html pages.

Answer (score 2):

Check [turn.js](http://www.turnjs.com) "is a JavaScript library that will make your content look like a real book or magazine using all the advantages of HTML5. The web is getting beautiful with new user interfaces based in HTML5; turn.js is the best fit for a magazine, book or catalog based in HTML5."

Or a [simple turorial](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/casestudies/20things_pageflip/) for the flip effect with HTML5 canvas.