# Mobile Jquery - Flip Effect

Tags: jquery, html

Please find the URL below.

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/pages/page-transitions.html

How can I use these effects on page onload or on document.onReady??

Comment: Are you using jquery mobile? If you are not, are you using AJAX page loads? The reason these transitions work on jQuery Mobile is because all page loads are partial. If you are loading a whole page, the transition effect will not be very smooth as it will not run until after the page has fully loaded.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Nathan, Ya I'm using Ajax (loading external html pages in a div tag using "load" function.

Comment: Which of these effects would you like to emulate? Each one is going to be different.

Comment: I'm trying to use Flip effect Nathan.

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML5 - Page turn effect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10483414/html5-page-turn-effect)

Answer (score 10):

Recreating the flip transition from jQuery Mobile on a standard page is fairly straightforward. Start by creating an absolutely positioned container with two relatively positioned children which will be the two pages you are flipping between. Once you have both pages loaded, apply the 'flip' and 'out' classes to the page being replaced and call `hide()` on it. Finally, add the 'flip' and 'in' classes to the page being displayed and call `show()` on it.

The transitions are just CSS3 transforms so just be mindful that they won't work on all browsers and they may behave poorly on large screens/low performance machines.

**HTML**

```
<button type="button" id="go">FLIP</button>
<div class="container">
    <div class="page1">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
    </div>
    <div class="page2">
        Duis interdum, odio vel condimentum varius, nibh nunc ultrices velit.
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
    position: absolute;   
    -webkit-perspective: 1000;
    -moz-perspective: 1000;
}
.page1 {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background: red;
    position: relative;
}
.page2 {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background: blue;
    position: relative;
    display: none;
}

.flip {
    -webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;
    -webkit-transform:translateX(0); 
    -moz-backface-visibility:hidden;
    -moz-transform:translateX(0);
}
.flip.out {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(-90deg) scale(.9);
    -webkit-animation-name: flipouttoleft;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 175ms;
    -moz-transform: rotateY(-90deg) scale(.9);
    -moz-animation-name: flipouttoleft;
    -moz-animation-duration: 175ms;
}
.flip.in {
    -webkit-animation-name: flipintoright;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 225ms;
    -moz-animation-name: flipintoright;
    -moz-animation-duration: 225ms;
}
.flip.out.reverse {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg) scale(.9);
    -webkit-animation-name: flipouttoright;
    -moz-transform: rotateY(90deg) scale(.9);
    -moz-animation-name: flipouttoright;
}
.flip.in.reverse {
    -webkit-animation-name: flipintoleft;
    -moz-animation-name: flipintoleft;
}
@-webkit-keyframes flipouttoleft {
    from { -webkit-transform: rotateY(0); }
    to { -webkit-transform: rotateY(-90deg) scale(.9); }
}
@-moz-keyframes flipouttoleft {
    from { -moz-transform: rotateY(0); }
    to { -moz-transform: rotateY(-90deg) scale(.9); }
}
@-webkit-keyframes flipouttoright {
    from { -webkit-transform: rotateY(0) ; }
    to { -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg) scale(.9); }
}
@-moz-keyframes flipouttoright {
    from { -moz-transform: rotateY(0); }
    to { -moz-transform: rotateY(90deg) scale(.9); }
}
@-webkit-keyframes flipintoleft {
    from { -webkit-transform: rotateY(-90deg) scale(.9); }
    to { -webkit-transform: rotateY(0); }
}
@-moz-keyframes flipintoleft {
    from { -moz-transform: rotateY(-90deg) scale(.9); }
    to { -moz-transform: rotateY(0); }
}
@-webkit-keyframes flipintoright {
    from { -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg) scale(.9); }
    to { -webkit-transform: rotateY(0); }
}
@-moz-keyframes flipintoright {
    from { -moz-transform: rotateY(90deg) scale(.9); }
    to { -moz-transform: rotateY(0); }
}
```

**JavaScript**

You'll need to replace this part with something more relevant to your page, but the concept will be the same.

```
$('#go').click(function() {
    var page1 = $('.page1');
    var page2 = $('.page2');
    var toHide = page1.is(':visible') ? page1 : page2 ;
    var toShow = page2.is(':visible') ? page1 : page2 ;

    toHide.removeClass('flip in').addClass('flip out').hide();
    toShow.removeClass('flip out').addClass('flip in').show();
});
```

Here is a working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/lakario/VPjX9/