# Front side/back side flip effect on div displaying image

Tags: jquery

I am trying to have an image flip around effect like what's used on www.eharmony.com.  When you mouseover a photo it spins around and displays more information.

[image: New div shown after mouseover]
I've found a JQuery component called Flip (http://lab.smashup.it/flip), but I'm having trouble getting it to work on the mouseover event. It also won't display a whole new div.  I was wondering if there's a better one out there.

Perhaps if someone can teach me how to fish by telling me what I can use to reverse engineer the eHarmony page, that would be incredibly useful. I've examined the HTML and see they have  divs labeled "flip-container", "back face", and "front face", but I can't figure out what Javascript calls are performing the actual flipping function. (I'm not so well versed at debugging Javascript.)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10602870/752527

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'll give this one a try! So far this looks like what I want.

Comment: I tried this out and it works great! Thanks so much. I couldn't find that code after days of searching...

Comment: Im glad that you got it working bro.